# Setar valor com voz em um editText

Tags: java, android, mobile

Quando aperto o botao falo o nome por exemplo potencia ele coloca o autofocus no editText, porem quando ele esta com o focus no edittext deveria apertar o botao e dizer o valor a ser escrito naquele campo, alguém me ajuda por favor.

essa é a mainActivity.java

```
private final int REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT = 100;
EditText potencia;
EditText tensao;
EditText corrente;
Button calcular;
View v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private void promptSpeechInput(){
    Intent it = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Diga Algo");
    try{
        startActivityForResult(it,REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException a){
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT: {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String mensagem = result.get(0);
                potencia = findViewById(R.id.potencia);
                tensao = findViewById(R.id.tensao);
                corrente = findViewById(R.id.corrente);
                calcular = findViewById(R.id.calcular);
                v = findViewById(R.id.view);
                if(mensagem.equals("potência")){
                    potencia.requestFocus();
                }else
                if(mensagem.equals("tensão")){
                    tensao.requestFocus();
                }else
                if(mensagem.equals("corrente")){
                    corrente.requestFocus();
                }else
                if(mensagem.equals("calcular")){
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void Falar(View view) {
    promptSpeechInput();
}
```

}

essa é a activit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Potência" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/potencia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Tensão" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tensao"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Corrente" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/corrente"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Resistência" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/resistencia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calcular"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Microfone"
    android:onClick="Falar"
    />
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro pra mim, mas você deseja que quando o `EditText` ganhe o foco o `Speech Recognition` seja ativado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esse trecho chama o onActivityResult()
>   **startActivityForResult(it,REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT);**

**Eu comentei as linhas que foram adicionadas e expliquei a logica delas dentro do codigo.**

```
private final int REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT = 100;
private String textViewFocus = ""; //Adicionei essa linha pra voce saber quem esta com Focus quando chamar novamente o onActivityResult()
EditText potencia;
EditText tensao;
EditText corrente;
Button calcular;
View v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private void promptSpeechInput(){
    Intent it = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    it.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Diga Algo");
    try{
        startActivityForResult(it,REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException a){
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPECH_INPUT: {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)  {
                ArrayList<String> result = 
                data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String mensagem = result.get(0);
                potencia = findViewById(R.id.potencia);
                tensao = findViewById(R.id.tensao);
                corrente = findViewById(R.id.corrente);
                calcular = findViewById(R.id.calcular);
                v = findViewById(R.id.view);
                if(mensagem.equals("potência")){
                    potencia.requestFocus();
                    if(potencia.hasFocus()) {
                        promptSpeechInput()
                        textViewFocus = "potencia";
                    } //Caso esteja com Focus, chama o metodo de Voz novamente.    
                }
                else if(mensagem.equals("tensão")){
                    tensao.requestFocus();
                    if(mensagem.hasFocus()) {
                        promptSpeechInput()
                        textViewFocus = "tensão";
                    }
                }
                else if(mensagem.equals("corrente")){
                    corrente.requestFocus();
                    if(corrente.hasFocus()) {
                        promptSpeechInput()
                        textViewFocus = "corrente";
                    }
                }
                else if(mensagem.equals("calcular")){
                    if(calcular.hasFocus()) {
                        promptSpeechInput()
                        textViewFocus = "calcular";
                    }
                }else {
                    //Essa ultima condicao vai verificar se algo diferente dos textos acima foi dito e entao inserir no textView q tem Focus True
                    switch (textViewFocus) {
                        case "potencia" :
                        potencia.setText(mensagem); // Fiz so o exemplo de potencia pra voce testar, caso de certo e so replicar
                        break;
                    }
                }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
public void Falar(View view) {
    promptSpeechInput();
}
```